# How to merge push just after all unit-tests pass?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

i want to change my CI so that every push to origin/master is tested on the CI-Server first and only if the tests pass the push gets merged.

Do you know any tools for this?

Kind regards

Comment: Bordering on off topic since it's about a tool recommendation, but never the less very interesting to see the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible workflow :

1. Work with two remote clones : `origin` and `ci`
2. Forbid pushes to `origin/master` by users other than the ci user
3. Push to `ci/master`
4. If the ci validates master HEAD, have the ci user push changes from its `ci` repo to `origin/master`

Comment: Good points! Thank you! How would you set this up with a team 25 Developers where commits appear very frequently? Would you give every developer his own "remote ci branch"?